# Logitech QuickCam Sphere has Blue Tint after 10.04 Ubuntu Upgrade

Tags: linux, ubuntu, logitech-webcam

After upgrading Ubuntu to 10.04, my `Logitech, Inc. QuickCam Orbit/Sphere AF` now has a blue tint in both Skype and guvcview (So probably everything).

Anyone run into this problem? I am going to run my updates to see if this helps for the time being.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running updates resolved this issue for me.  It also broke my X with my nvidia card but I just went into to "Hardware Devices", disabled the nvidia driver, and then re-enabled it and it was fine after a reboot.